# How to retrieve selected value from ionic popover modal

Tags: typescript, ionic4

I'm creating simple ionic 4 angular app, and use ionic popover modal. here below code show my open popover modal

```
//home.page.ts
async openModal(ev: Event) {
const modal = await this.popoverController.create({
  component: ModalPage,
  componentProps: {
    avatar: this.item_list //item list is array of two element id and name
  }
});
modal.onDidDismiss().then((dataReturned) => {
  if (dataReturned !== null) {
    // dataReturned.data;
    alert('Modal Sent Data :' + dataReturned);
    console.log('Modal Sent Data :' + dataReturned);
  }
});
return await modal.present();
}
```

Below code for modal

```
//ModalPage.page.ts
closeModal(data: any) {
this.popoverController.dismiss(data);
}
}
```

Below code ModalPage.page.html

```
 <ion-row>
  <div *ngFor="let item of item_list">
    <ion-col>
      <button ion-button 
    (click)="closeModal($event)">
        <ion-icon 
       [src]="item.avatar"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-col>
  </div>
</ion-row>
```

how to retrieve value from modal when click on button and dismiss called to send value to home.page.ts and display on home.page.html ?

Comment: have you got any error? are you sure you using popover not modal?

Answer (score 0):

You are asking help for modal but you using a popoverController. Anyway, you can get value this way using [ion-modal](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal).

> home.ts

```
....
import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
....
constructor(public modalController: ModalController) {}
....
async presentModal() {
  const modal = await this.modalController.create({
    component: ModalPage,
    componentProps: {
       avatar: this.item_list //item list is array of two element id and name
    }
  });
modal.onDidDismiss().then((dataReturned) => {
    if (dataReturned !== null) {
      // dataReturned.data;
      alert('Modal Sent Data :' + dataReturned);
      console.log('Modal Sent Data :' + dataReturned);
    }
  });
  return await modal.present();
}
```

> ModalPage.page.ts

```
closeModal(data: any) {
  this.modalController.dismiss(data);
}
```

> ModalPage.page.html

```
  <ion-row>
    <div *ngFor="let item of item_list">
      <ion-col>
        <button ion-button (click)="closeModal($event)">
          <ion-icon [src]="item.avatar"></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </ion-col>
    </div>
  </ion-row>
```

Hope this help yoou :)

Note: **[popoverController](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/popover)** and **[modalController](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal)** both components and their usage is different.

Answer (score 0):

I'm simply pass parameter in button click event click(item) and get click data.

```
<ion-row>
<div *ngFor="let item of item_list">
  <ion-col>
    <button ion-button (click)="closeModal(item)">
      <ion-icon [src]="item.avatar"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-col>
</div>
```